# How to filter a Spark RDD based on particular field value in Java?

Tags: java, filter, apache-spark

I am creating a Spark job in Java. Here is my code.

I am trying to filter records from a CSV file. Header contains fields `OID`, `COUNTRY_NAME`, ......

Instead of just filtering based on `s.contains("CANADA")`, I would like to be more specific, like I want to filter based on `COUNTRY_NAME.equals("CANADA")`.
Any thoughts on how I can do this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String gaimFile = "hdfs://xx.yy.zz.com/sandbox/data/acc/mydata"; 

    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Filter App");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    try{
        JavaRDD<String> gaimData = sc.textFile(gaimFile);

        JavaRDD<String> canadaOnly = gaimData.filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = -4438640257249553509L;

            public Boolean call(String s) { 
               // My file id csv with header OID, COUNTRY_NAME, .....
               // here instead of just saying s.contains 
               // i would like to be more specific and say 
               // if COUNTRY_NAME.eqauls("CANADA)
               return s.contains("CANADA"); 
            }
        }); 

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("ERROR: G9 MatchUp Failed");
    }
    finally{
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to map your values into a custom class first:

```
rdd.map(lines=>ConvertToCountry(line))
   .filter(country=>country == "CANADA")

class Country{
  ...ctor that takes an array and fills properties...
  ...properties for each field from the csv...
}

ConvertToCountry(line: String){
  return new Country(line.split(','))
}
```

The above is a combination of Scala and pseudocode, but you should get the point.